# Web scraping a webpage for nested table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get some information from this page : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM2437275

where I am particularly interested in extracting the Characteristics data as follows:

```
group_id: xxx
medicore_id: xxxxxxx
date_of_visit_sample_drawn_date: xxxxxxx
rin: xxxxxx
donor_id: xxxxx
sle_visit_designation: xxxxxxx
bold_shipment_batch: xxxxxx
rna_concentrated: xxxxxx
subject_type: xxxxxxx
```

so on and so forth.
Upon inspecting the page, I realize that this information is deeply nested within other larger tables and that there is no special class/id for me to effectively parse for the characteristics information.
I have been unsuccessfully trying to look for table within tables but I find that sometimes not all tables are being read. This is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source= requests.get("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?
acc=GSM2437275").text


soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table') 
for i in table:
  print i.prettify()
print (len(table)) #22 tables

print (table[6].prettify()) #narrow down on relevant table
table = table[6]

table_subtables = table.find_all('table')
for i in table_subtables:
   print (i.prettify())

print len(table_subtables) #14 tables

tbb = table_subtables[1] 

tbb_subtable = tbb.find_all('table')
for i in tbb_subtable:
  print (i.prettify())
print len(tbb_subtable) #12 tables

tbbb = tbb_subtable[5] 

    tbbb_subtable = tbbb.find_all('table')
for i in tbbb_subtable:
  print (i.prettify())
print len(tbbb_subtable) # 6 tables
```

so on and so forth. However, as I keep doing this, I find that not all tables are being read. Can someone point me to a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scrape the data with regular expressions and `urllib` to specifically scrape the keywords and their corresponding values:

```
import re
import urllib 
data = str(urllib.urlopen('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM2437275').read())
target_vals = ['group_id', 'medicore_id', 'date_of_visit_sample_drawn_date', 'rin', 'donor_id', 'sle_visit_designation', 'bold_shipment_batch', 'rna_concentrated', 'subject_type']
final_data = {i:re.findall('(?<={}:\s)\w+'.format(i), data)[0] for i in target_vals}
```

Output:

```
{
 'date_of_visit_sample_drawn_date': '2009', 
 'rna_concentrated': 'No', 
  'sle_visit_designation': 'Baseline', 
  'rin': '8', 
  'subject_type': 'Patient', 
  'donor_id': '19', 
  'bold_shipment_batch': '1', 
  'medicore_id': 'B0019V1', 
  'group_id': 'A'
}
```

Edit: given multiple links, you can create a `pandas` dataframe out of the generated data for each:

```
import re
import urllib
import pandas as pd
def get_data_from_links(link, target_vals=['group_id', 'medicore_id', 'date_of_visit_sample_drawn_date', 'rin', 'donor_id', 'sle_visit_designation', 'bold_shipment_batch', 'rna_concentrated', 'subject_type']):
    data = str(urllib.urlopen(link).read())
    return {i:re.findall('(?<={}:\s)\w+'.format(i), data)[0] for i in target_vals}
returned_data = get_data_from_links('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM2437275')
df = pd.DataFrame([returned_data])
```

Output:

```
  bold_shipment_batch date_of_visit_sample_drawn_date donor_id group_id  \
  0                   1                            2009       19        A   

  medicore_id rin rna_concentrated sle_visit_designation subject_type  
      0     B0019V1   8               No              Baseline      Patient
```

If you have a list of links you would like to retrieve your data from, you can construct a table by constructing a nested dictionary of the resulting data to pass to `DataFrame.from_dict`:

```
link_lists = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3']
final_data = {i:get_data_from_links(i) for i in link_lists}
new_table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_data, orient='index')
```

Output (assuming the first link is `'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM2437275'`):

```
       rin rna_concentrated date_of_visit_sample_drawn_date  \
link1   8               No                            2009   

  sle_visit_designation bold_shipment_batch group_id subject_type  \
link1              Baseline                   1        A      Patient   

  medicore_id donor_id  
link1     B0019V1       19
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very helpful! Is there a way I can store the descriptions such as "date_of_visit_sample_drawn_date" as a column name and the corresponding value under that column? Also, it I were to provide a vector of several links to the variable data, would it store all the information under these column headings from all the given webpages?

Comment: @NithishaKh glad to help! Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

The way Ajax1234 has shown in his solution is definitely the best way to go with. However, if hardcoded index is not a barrier and if you wish to avoid using regex to achieve the same then this is another approach you may think of trying:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

res = requests.get("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSM2437275")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
for items in soup.select("td[style*='justify']")[2:3]:
    data = '\n'.join([item for item in items.strings][:9])
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
group_id: A
medicore_id: B0019V1
date_of_visit_sample_drawn_date: 2009-09-14
rin: 8.5
donor_id: 19
sle_visit_designation: Baseline
bold_shipment_batch: 1
rna_concentrated: No
subject_type: Patient
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been reading up on using BeautifulSoup so having this alternative solution is very helpful!